# Caching JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, caching

I've never really cached data before, but I feel as though it will greatly improve my site.

Basically, I pull JSON data from an external API that helps the basic functionality of my website.  This info doesn't really change that often yet my users pull the info from the API thousands of times a day. If it updated once a day, that would be fine.  I want to run a cron job daily that will pull the info and update the cache.

I already tried a few different things, both pulled using PHP:

1) Store data in an SQL table

    I had it working, but there's no reason why I should ping the database each time when I can just store it in basic HTML/JSON.

2) .JSON file (using `fwrite`)

    I had it stored, but the only way this worked is if the `.getJSON()` callback function is prepended to the JSON data and then the data is surrounded by parentheses (making it jsonp, I believe).

Does anyone have any advice or any directions to lead me in?  As I said, I've never really done anything like this so I don't even know if I'm remotely headed in the right direction.

Edit:

Okay so I talked to my hosting and since I'm on a shared hosting (dreamhost) I can't install memcached, which sucks.  The only info they could give me was that if it is on http://pecl.php.net/ then I can most likely use it.  They said APC is available.  I'm not sure if this fits my problem.  I'd like to be able to access the cache directly in jQuery.  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use memcached. Memcached is an in-memory key-value store for small chunks of arbitrary data (strings, objects) from results of database calls, API calls, or page rendering. Very easy to implement and has a low system footprint.

Comment: Nice, I'll look into it and report back with any issues. Thanks!

Comment: I have 13 or so different years with about 50 data sets in each of them.  Should I just throw it all together as one big JSON sorted by year, or separate data sets? Can I even do that in `memcached`?

Comment: You can make the key the year and JSOn data as the value. Which ever is less / cleaner code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use memcached, go back to your database option and store it in a table using the [MEMORY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) engine.

Answer (score 1):

try [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php).  You can easily generate a string key and store whatever blob of json you want with it.  works like a dictionary, except persists in memory.

There's an option to give it an expiration time (otherwise it just stays cached forever).  So when the user requests the data, just check if it's stored in memcached.  If it is, great, return it.  If it's not, do whatever you do to build it, then put it in memcached with a 24 hour expiration.

Answer (score 0):

If your data varies per user:

I've done this by storing an object in the $_SESSION array.

I attach a quick bit of logic that determines if the data expiry period is up. If so, it draws new data, serves and caches. If not, it draws from $_SESSION and serves it up.

Comment: If you do this, you're storing the same data once per user rather than once for the entire site.

Comment: Yep. My data was per user. Not sure what his is.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Redis](http://redis.io/). 
And to store data easily without unexpected errors on set/get - encode it using base64.

Comment: If it doesn't change really often - you can create CRON task, that pulls it from remote server once an hour for example. And store it in static JS file.

Answer (score 0):

this to store:

```
file_put_contents($path, $json_text);
```

and this to restore:

```
$json_text = file_get_contents($path);
echo $json_text;
```

`echo` can be used to pass the json exactly as it comes from the http request. if you need to parse it into a variable (in javascript) you can use `array = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json_text; ?>');`. if you need to parse in php, use `$array = json_decode($json_text);`.